# How to configure toolchains plugin in m2e / Installed maven in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, maven-toolchains-plugin

Currently i am using **maven(Apache Maven 3.3.9)** **& Java(Java version: 1.8.0_91)** installed in  my windows machine. I have a java application which was developed using **Java Version 1.6.0_31**.

Since **Apache maven(3.3.9)** is not directly compatible with the previous version of Java(Prior to 1.8) I have included **[toolchains plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html)** to compile and run the project with **Java 1.6**.  I can do a successful build using command prompt.

But when I try to build the same project using eclipse with **eclipse m2e plugin** or by adding the **external maven(3.3.9)** using *eclipse->Windows->Preferences->Maven->Installations*, I am getting the below error.

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Expected root element 'settings' but found 'toolchains' (position: START_TAG seen ...OOLCHAINS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/toolchains-1.1.0.xsd">... @45:114)  @ U:\POC\Repo\.m2\toolchains.xml, line 45, column 114
[WARNING] 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Replenishment Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Replenishment ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\xagh9\workspace\Replenishment\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-toolchains-plugin:1.1:toolchain (default) @ Replenishment ---
[INFO] Required toolchain: jdk [ vendor='sun' version='1.6' ]
[ERROR] No toolchain found for type jdk
[ERROR] Cannot find matching toolchain definitions for the following toolchain types:
jdk [ vendor='sun' version='1.6' ]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.105 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-04T12:02:08+11:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/116M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-toolchains-plugin:1.1:toolchain (default) on project Replenishment: Cannot find matching toolchain definitions for the following toolchain types:
[ERROR] jdk [ vendor='sun' version='1.6' ]
[ERROR] Please make sure you define the required toolchains in your ~/.m2/toolchains.xml file.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**Note:**  With Java_1.8 I can build the project successfully without toolchains plugin. But with toolchains plugin configured I am facing this issues. Can anyone help me to resolve this.

***The required toolchains.xml is present in both maven config folder as well as in the .m2 folder of the repository***

UPDATE:
Maven compiler plugin configuration:
[image: Plugin]

Comment: Try setting compiler source and target, https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: @ravthiru I have tried this one already. Also updated my question. Still it is not working. Getting the same error.

Comment: Just for the record. Maven 3.3.9 needs Java 1.7 as minimum...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, for my eclipse I have java run-time as 1.8 and in the build path i have 1.6. Any how I have identified the fix and posted my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resolved after changing goals in eclipse run configuration as below.

[image: Eclipse run configuration]

The problem is eclipse is not automatically reading the toolchains.xml. We have to manually specify in the goals. I fixed this by referring the [this Link](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html)